# Comparing strings in PHP that should match

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP file. I have the following definition for a variable:

```
$GLOBALS['B'] = "CHOFER NO DISPONIBLE";
```

Later, the value of $GLOBALS['B'] may change.
Then I try to compare the value of $GLOBALS['B'] to call a function, like this:

```
if (strcmp( $GLOBALS['B'],"CHOFER NO DISPONIBLE") == 0){
...
}

else {
...}
```

but the if clause is never called, it always goes to the else path.
I am sure that $GLOBALS['B'] value is not changed.

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Try debugging with a var_dump to see if the two are the same length, no hidden characters or whitespace, or charset differences

Comment: But the dangers of using globals is that they can be changed without your realising it, and it's very difficult for you to find out where it happens; that's why it's generally considered bad practise to use them